# Newid() equivalent in BASE SAS

Tags: sas

I am using BASE SAS 9.2 and i have a doubt related to generating unique identifiers. In MS-SQL we have an option to create unique identifiers using NEWID() function
Is there any such option in BASE SAS or if not how can i generate unique identifiers in BASE SAS

Thanks,
Sachi

Comment: There isn't a direct correlation, as SAS is usually used for analysis (Statistical Analysis Software) rather than DBMS and the ID is part of a DBMS.  However, if you explain more of what you need from this ID and how you expect it to function perhaps we can suggest other answers.

Comment: I needed to mask People's identity like Names, account numbers with alphanumeric ID's. Hence require this. Also i should be able to get back Names, account numbers when i reverse engineer this alphaNumeric IDs

Comment: That's a totally different question that the one you asked above...

Answer (score 0):

Such identifiers need to be manually configured, according to your needs.  A basic approach (assuming your identifier is numeric) may follow along the lines of:

```
/* get previous maximum id and store in macro variable */
proc sql noprint;
select max(identifier) into: max_identifier from MainTable;

/* generate new identifier starting from previous high value */
data append;
   retain identifier &max_identifier;
   set staging; 
   identifier+1; 
run;

proc append base=MainTable data=append; run;
```